# Is there a way to hide the main file from log4net c#?

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there a way to hide the main file used for log4net c#?
When you use log4net, you set in the config file the path where to create the log file and to log there.
The name of the file from the Path is where logging is happening and based on that I create a file each hour when I log something.

I can set the file to hidden but than I don't have access to it.

Can you please help me with a solution where I can still create log files each hour based on the config file, but the main File which is accessed by the process to be hidden? I have looked for something like this but I haven't found nothing.

Here is the code I use:

```
<appender name="ExampleLog" type="RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMddHH" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="240" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <CountDirection value="1" />
    <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyy/MM/dd    HH:mm:ss:fff} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

public override void OpenFile(string fileName, bool append)
{
      fileName = File;
      FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
      fileInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;
      base.OpenFile(fileName, append);
}
```

Comment: what "main file" you refer to?

Comment: to the Log.txt, I want that File to be hidden, but to create files each hour based on that. As you can see, I set in the config the dataPattern, that is used to create a file each hour, but when I set the Log.txt to hidden, the folder also is hidden

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** place the current log file in a hidden subfolder and the rolled files in the root folder. No need to override the appender in the code.

**Details:**
Your log4net config should look like this:

```
  <appender name="ExampleLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Log\\Current\\.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="'..\\'yyyyMMddHH" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="240" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <CountDirection value="1" />
    <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyy/MM/dd    HH:mm:ss:fff} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Note that file value doesn't have a filename and the dataPattern has a leading '..\\'. Also, PreserveLogFileNameExtension should be set to true.

You can create the subfolder (Current) and make it hidden once programmatically.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, I tried your way, it did help very much, but when I try to hide programmatically the subfolder, is not completely hidden, it's easy visible, but still your answer was very good because now I can try something else, a way to move the each file created every hour in a folder, because that's what I need to have my folder

Comment: What do you mean it is not completely hidden. When the folder is created for the first time "by log4net" it is not hidden. So, it's best if you create the "log\\curret" folder (if it doesn't exist) before log4net starts and make it hidden.

Comment: Ok, I taught that you said to create it by log4net, my fault, I will try like you said than